# Don't know how to use namespace of one project in another

Tags: c#, namespaces, using, jetbrains-rider

I'm new to C# and JetBrains Rider and I'm having trouble using a namespace of a project in another project. I have one project with a namespace called `math` which I want to test through unit tests in a different project. The problem is that the namespace cannot be found.

[Solution Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVdZm.png)

Any help?

I updated both Target Frameworks to `.NETFramework v4.7.1`.

I tried using references by right click on test project `Properties` -> `Reference Paths` and then adding the path of project directory and path of script directory but to no avail.

- Update

@gunr2171
The problem is that I cant add a reference or atleast I dont know how. The reference option isn't availible for the project.
[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIhQm.png)

Comment: It sounds like you need to make a Project Reference. "Reference Paths" look to be for direct DLL additions.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Extending_Your_Solution.html#project_assembly_references

Comment: You need a "using" statement.  You also may need to full path of the namespace.  Namespaces are nested like subdirectories.  The using statement allow you to use just the namespace instead of requiring the full namespace with parents.

Comment: @gunr2171 I added an update